# Add new Guard to auth.php file my laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-5.6

I started to create Admin login laravel package for learning purpose, In this package i need to add add guards and providers to the auth.php file from my package.

From Laravel documentation, I got to Know we can add configuration file to 
project config folder from service provider boot method as follow.

```
   public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/path/to/config/courier.php' => config_path('courier.php'),
    ]);
}
```

But how to add my config file to merge with config/auth.php file.

And what the following lines of code will do, i am not getting from laravel documentation.

```
public function register()
{
    $this->mergeConfigFrom(
        __DIR__.'/path/to/config/courier.php', 'courier'
    );
}
```

And following is my custom service provider code

```
<?php

namespace Abhilash\AdminLogin;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class AdminLoginServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/config/admin.php' => config_path('auth.php'),
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
       $this->mergeConfigFrom(
            __DIR__.'/config/admin.php', 'auth'
        );

    }

    /**
     * Merge the given configuration with the existing configuration.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mergeConfigFrom($path, $key)
    {
        $config = $this->app['config']->get($key, []);

        $this->app['config']->set($key, $this->mergeConfigs(require $path, $config));
    }

    /**
     * Merges the configs together and takes multi-dimensional arrays into account.
     *
     * @param  array  $original
     * @param  array  $merging
     * @return array
     */
    protected function mergeConfigs(array $original, array $merging)
    {
        $array = array_merge($original, $merging);

        foreach ($original as $key => $value) {
            if (! is_array($value)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (! Arr::exists($merging, $key)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (is_numeric($key)) {
                continue;
            }

            $array[$key] = $this->mergeConfigs($value, $merging[$key]);
        }

        return $array;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't merge configs as it doesn't merge multidimensional arrays and depending on the content of these configs or their complexity, it may get messy. Summary, It will merge the content of `$key` with `$value` of your config. But what you can do is either `override` the `mergeConfigFrom` in your `ServiceProvider` or you can create a new function and use it on the `register`, like such:

```
/**
  * Merges the configs together and takes multi-dimensional arrays into account.
  *
  * @param  array  $original
  * @param  array  $merging
  * @return array
  */
 protected function mergeConfigs(array $original, array $merging) {
    $array = array_merge($original, $merging);
    foreach ($original as $key => $value) {
       if (! is_array($value)) {
          continue;
       }
       if (! Arr::exists($merging, $key)) {
          continue;
       }
       if (is_numeric($key)) {
          continue;
       }
       $array[$key] = $this->mergeConfig($value, $merging[$key]);
     }
     return $array;
 }
```

Disclaimer: I'm not the author but I've used this function once and it works as expected, [here's the original](https://medium.com/@koenhoeijmakers/properly-merging-configs-in-laravel-packages-a4209701746d)

Comment: This is not working for me, when will merging of configs happens, do i need to run any additional commands.

Comment: php artisan vendor:publish  and tell me what's wrong. Is there an error or what is the result

Comment: I have edited my question by adding service provider code, when i run php artisan vendor:publish no changes in auth.php file

Comment: @Abhilash.k.p do not that you are modifying the configuration on real-time and not updating the file original auth file.